# Side pull rear brake is weaker after changing the cable

Tags: brakes, rim-brake

I bought an old city bike (and I think I overpaid for it) and after a couple of weeks both front and rear brake cables snapped the same day.

It has side pull brakes. I changed both of the cables, but the brakes don't feel as strong as before, especially the rear brake. Note that I adjusted the rear brake pads before installing the cables.

- What did I do wrong?
- Should I also change the tubing? If yes, should I put oil/grease inside the tube?

PS. I am planning to change the brake pads with leather face pads for rainy days anyway.

Here are some photos (ignore the uncut brake cable, click for larger):
[image: lever]
[image: cable]
[image: cable]
[image: rear brake]
[image: front brake]

---

### UPDATE

I have changed the brake pads, I have put some oil inside the tube for the rear brake. While I am at it I have also put some oil around the center pivot bolt so both calipers can move with less friction.

For a couple of days it was worse than before. But now I think the new brake pads have worn out a little bit and fit to their position better and they are strong enough. The rear brake still feels a little bit weaker but it is much better.

Here is the old brake pad and the new brake pad. The old one is worn away pretty badly.
[image: old and new brake pad]

I will also try to install ferrules soon.

Comment: Did you replace the cables *without* filling the sheath with oil? Keeping the inside of the cable oily is #1 thing to do. (and oil the pivot point in the middle of the brakes too)

Comment: I did not apply any oil inside the sheath, I can do it in the following days and I will report the results.

Comment: It is regular maintenance. Pull the cable out of the caliper. Hold it vertical. Try to run thin oil or chain lube down the inner, while sliding the sheath up and down. Do this until oil comes through the bottom.

Comment: But don't get oil on the pads or rims!!

Comment: Modern outers are teflon-lined so adding oil and lubes are redundant, and will clag it up over time.

Comment: But (@Criggie) are they modern outers? And there are cheap ones for sale that are either unlined or with a thin coating of some other plastic

Comment: They are not modern at all :)

Comment: If there is extra friction in the cables, get modern Teflon lined outer cables instead of oiling them. With ferrules ;)

Comment: @nimcap generally speaking I'd change inners and outers together.  You can get away with outers every second annual inner change, but many of the bikes I see have  gone years and decades without a change.   A cheap set of inners and outers for both brakes is ~$7.

Comment: I'm speculating: did you (unintentionally) change the path of the cable in some way? Such that where it is in the outer it makes tighter turns, an extra loop, …? I don't see anything like that in pictures but have seen that causing problems once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to see what the surface of the brake pads looks like and how it is aligned with the rim, but I would look to see how flat the pad surfaces are and how flush they are with each side of the rim... when the brakes are pulled on.

If the pads have developed a concave profile where they used to fit on the rim, and don't fit there any more, it could explain reduced braking power. Replace the pads if they are no longer flush with the rim.

The black outer cables should have metal ferrules on the ends, in photos 2 & 3 at least. They’ll help, but if they weren’t there before then it doesn’t explain the reduction in power you’ve had. I would also thread in that brake adjuster on the top brake arm, all the way down (back off the locknut first).

Comment: Yeah, there should be ferrules, and the adjuster should be threaded about 3/4s of the way in to start with, then unscrewed over time as the pads wear.

Comment: OP's lack of metal or hard plastic ferrules over the end of every cut means that there's a tiny amount of flex/squish, and its adding up.  Ferrules are a very good idea.

Comment: @criggie for sure, I’ve reinforced the ferrule aspect. Thanks

Comment: I think the concave profile you have mentioned is causing the issue. I can even see the contact surface is smaller than before. I will replace the brake pads as soon as possible.

Comment: @nimcap it’s consistent with drop in power hopefully that will help. They’re older style brakes so get the best pads you can find and afford, if there’s even much choice nowadays. Could be a question in itself... what makes a good pad for these style brakes and chromed rims

Comment: We avoid product recommendations generally, but koolstop pads are excellent and worth the money.  Any decent LBS will have the right pads/fittings.

Comment: @criggie I can't really see how you get less "squish" when you have steel pressing on plastic ferrule, than steel directly on steel. The ferrule reduces the aperture for water to enter the cable, prevents direct electrolytic corrosion where the steel cable would meet aluminium, stops the sharp cut end of spring steel chiseling into the aluminium, and hides the rust  and cut end so it looks neater (probably the actual function). As this is a steel frame, they are probably not needed.

Comment: @HenryCrun sounds like a good question "why do we need ferrules on brake cables?"

Comment: @henrycrun when the cable outer is compressed by cable tension, it wants to deform outwards. The ferrule is a close fit to the outer cable so restrains the cut end from bulging outwards, or ‘squishing’. This deformation would otherwise soak up a little of the braking force. Maybe there are other benefits too, but either way I think not using ferrules would be a ‘minority view’. Ps I advocate metal ferrules only for brake cables

Comment: @criggie too. Sometimes cable stops in the frame are a close enough fit that a ferrule doesn’t fit, like brake and lever ends in this example. But in that case the close fit of the cable stop is doing the same job, of restraining the bulging cable outer. The bike in question above does not have these kinds of cable stops in the frame, so needs this extra support on the outer cable ends.

Comment: @Swifty this is a different question.  Let Henry ask it properly, and not discuss in comments.

Comment: @criggie I welcome Henry asking properly and not discussing in comments